# Create a concave halfsphere with Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm a web developer with a good JavaScript experience, and I'm currently exploring [Three.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three.js) possibilities. However, I'm not very familiar with 3D shapes and vocabulary, and I can't figure out how to build the shape I need.

I want to create a halfsphere, and be able to project a video *inside* this sphere. I have a panoramic spherical video, and I need to distort it to make it look like "plane".

Thanks to Paul's tutorial, I have drawn a sphere and projected my video on it. But the external sphere surface is convex, and I need a concave one! How can I to achieve that? Extruding a smaller sphere out of my initial one?

Comment: Paul who? What tutorial? [Paul Lewis](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/three/intro/)? [Paul King](https://12devsofxmas.co.uk/2012/01/webgl-and-three-js/)? [Paul Irish](https://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a half-sphere by setting the additional `SphereGeometry` parameters:

```js
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( radius, widthSegments, heightSegments, phiStart, phiLength, thetaStart, thetaLength )
```

Experiment until you get exactly what you want.

You will also have to set the `side` property of the material you use for the sphere to either be `THREE.BackSide` or `THREE.DoubleSide`.

```js
material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

three.js r.143

Comment: Great ! This is exactly what I was looking for ! Here is the final code : `SphereGeometry(5000,16,16, Math.PI/2,  Math.PI*2, 0, Math.PI)` with `material.side = THREE.BackSide`

Answer (score 5):

You can use SphereBufferGeometry, to create a half sphere (hemisphere). The last argument does it: `0.5 * Math.PI`. Also to be able to see something, you need to use `THREE.DoubleSide` for *material*.

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(5, 8, 6, 0, 2*Math.PI, 0, 0.5 * Math.PI);
...
material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```