# creating a concave half-sphere using three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am trying to create a concave half-sphere using three.js (i.e. the inside of the half-sphere is the surface described rather than the outside). I don't just want the back side to be visible, I want to build a 3D object (e.g. for printing) that has a concave surface. I have attempted to achieve this by creating a half-sphere using SphereGeometry, and then reversing the outward direction (normal) of each face.

As I understand it the outward direction (normal) of a face is determined by the "right hand rule" (as described here in an STL context: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format) ). Simply, if a face is decribed by vertices (a, b, c) - in that order - then if you curl the fingers of your right hand following the order of the vertices (from a, to b, to c) your thumb points to the outward direction of the face.

This has worked to a point - if I export an STL file and view the result in an STL viewer (and explore the cross-section etc), it is clear the surface is concave (as desired). However something about the result makes it look like a convex sphere when rendered, as this jsfiddle shows: http://jsfiddle.net/vvUn3/8/ , the relevant portion of which is:

```
var geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(aRadius, cSegments, cSegments, 0, Math.PI);

for(var i = 0; i < geom.faces.length; i++) {
    var f = geom.faces[i];
    var tmp = f.a;
    f.a = f.c;
    f.c = tmp;
}

geom.computeFaceNormals();
geom.computeVertexNormals();

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
scene.add(mesh);
```

Clearly I'm missing something. Any ideas?

EDIT: this post: [Create a concave halfsphere with Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425014/create-a-concave-half-sphere-with-three-js) asks a similar question, but while they just want the inner side to be rendered using threejs, I wish the 3d model described (and exported e.g. to an STL file) to be the inner side.

Comment: Add `mesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide`. Does that help? http://jsfiddle.net/vvUn3/9/

Comment: If you want a printable 3D model, then you need to have thickness. For that your can use Constructive Solid Geometry. http://www.chandlerprall.com/2011/12/constructive-solid-geometry-with-three-js/ and http://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG

Comment: thanks, the DoubleSide addition makes it look better. However it does not change the exported STL file which, while concave, also doesn't look right. And I'd like to understand why I can't have a properly rendered inner side without the outer side painted too.

Comment: regarding CSG, i understand this won't be printable as is. But it could form part of a printable model.

Comment: @PeterMortensen three.js is not capitalized!