# A halfsphere in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm following the advice in *[Create a concave halfsphere with Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425014/create-a-concave-halfsphere-with-three-js)* to create a halfsphere in Three.js that I plan on mapping some fisheye video to. An example (with lens cap on) [is here](http://video-processing.s3.amazonaws.com/2016_0822_153754_015A.MP4).

I'm just trying to get the sphere to show first and it disappears whenever I try and turn it into a half sphere.

See the code at *http://codepen.io/bknill/pen/vXBWGv*.

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5000,16,16, Math.PI/2, Math.PI*2, 0, Math.PI);

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x2980b9});
material.side = THREE.BackSide;

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(sphere);
```

How can I get this halfsphere to show up?

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version of three.js?

Comment: How can you tell that ? I'm just using the version of three.js in this codepen i found. Where do I update it !?

Comment: It says in the console it's using r58; the settings of the codepen give that version. r80 is the current version. Changing that you may have to update the pen to run at all, but you're better off asking questions that run on the current version of the library.

Comment: It's running 80 now http://codepen.io/bknill/pen/vXBWGv